# .htaccess Rewrite rule for Angular SPA

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**THE PROBLEM**

The normal URL a user visits is:

```
http://www.example.com/reviews/view-course?courseID=933
```

However, I'm using angular routing and therefore this cannot be scraped say by Facebook or Twitter - so I'm trying to divert them to a page rendered on the server with the correct meta tags present.

**WHAT I'M TRYING**

This is what I'm trying but it just creates an endless loop on my server somehow, and Facebook for example, times out

```
# for social media crawlers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule /view-course(.*)$ http://www.example.com/social_scrape2/static-page?courseID=$1 [P]
```

**tl:dr** Basically, when a user clicks to share the page `http://www.example.com/reviews/view-course?courseID=933` on Facebook for example, I want Facebook, when it scrapes, to be redirected to `http://www.example.com/social_scrape2/static-page?courseID=933`

**ALSO TRIED**

```
RewriteRule ^reviews/view-course?courseID=(.*)$ http://www.example.com/social_scrape2/static-page?courseID=$1 [P]
```

[This page gave me the idea of how to do this if it helps at all](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app)

(added Angular tag as someone doing the same thing might be able to contribute)

**UPDATE**

This is all rewrite conditions in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^courseID=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^reviews/view-course$ /social_scrape2/static-page [P]

#angular html5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /reviews/index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^courseID=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^reviews/view-course$ /social_scrape2/static-page [L,R]
```

I've added the rewrite condition for the user-agent that made the request. This means only requests *initiated by* these user agents will trigger this rewrite rule. Since you can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, I moved that regex out into its own condition. The rest is identical to what you tried. This simply takes a request made by facebook, twitter, pinterest, etc for

```
http://www.example.com/reviews/view-course?courseID=(anything)
```

and **redirects** the request to:

```
http://www.example.com/social_scrape2/static-page?courseID=(anything)
```

Comment: That will redirect everyone though, no? It actually doesn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: @DarrenSweeney can add the condition that checks the user-agent, then. This only works if the rules are in the document root.

Comment: Thanks for that but don't understand I'm afraid - rewrite conditions are not even close to a strong point for me

Comment: Thanks again Jon but still nothing - I get this from Facebook `Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.` - My actual URL is `http://www.snaphookgolf.com/reviews/view-course?courseID=933` - gonna add complete `.htaccess` file to question

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Do you have mod_proxy enabled?

Comment: Jon, yes, mod_proxy is installed